# Programmatically dismiss modal dialog in MacOS

Tags: swift, macos, nsalert

I have a warning dialog from a MacOS application's AppDelegate that needs to be updated with new information.  When the new information is available, I want to programmatically dismiss the old dialog and present the new one.  I have tried this two ways, both with problems:

1. Using `alert.runModal()`

   If I use the above, a modal is presented as desired.  I can then dismiss the dialog later with `lockWarningModal.window.close()`, it works to make the old dialog disappear, **but it freezes the UI, so I can no longer interact with it.**  I am guessing this is because `alert.runModal()` is synchronous, and the main thread is still blocked.  However, I don't know how to release this.
2. Using `alert.beginSheetModal(for: NSApplication.shared.windows.last!) { (response) in }`

   If I use the above and dismiss the dialog with `NSApplication.shared.windows.last!.endSheet(alert.window)`, then this solves the UI freeze problem.  However, **the dialog is attached to the main application window** and is not brought to the front as a modal.

How can I achieve a modal dialog that is programmatically dismissible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stop a model event loop (or alert sheet) by simply closing its window. In fact, using the modern `NSAlert` API, you should never have to close or order out the window—the framework handles this for you.

For an alert started with `runModal()` use `NSApplication`'s `abortModal()`, `stopModal()`, or `stopModal(withCode:)`. After `runModal()` returns, send the alert window an `orderOut(nil)` to remove it.

For an alert sheet that executes a completion block afterwards, use `NSWindow`'s `endSheet(_)` or `endSheet(_:returnCode:)`. The alert will be automatically removed after your completion block executes.

Comment: Using `NSApplication.shared.abortModal()` works to keep the UI responsive after calling `lockWarningModal.window.close()`.  However, calling `NSApplication.shared.abortModal()` by itself does not close the window.  To your point "you should never have to close or order out the window—the framework handles this for you," am I doing something wrong by making both calls to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I probably overstated this a bit. If you're using `runModal()` (which is an old API), you should use `abortModal()` et. al. to programmatically stop the modal loop. In the code that handles the return value (after `runModal()` returns), send the alert window an `orderOut(nil)`. While you can, technically, "close" a dialog window, it doesn't make sense; these are not documents, you just want it to disappear. The thing to remember is this: do _not_ order out the alert panel before the model loop ends.

Comment: The modern API methods (`beginSheetModal(for:,completionHandler:)` et. al.) execute a completion block when the alert has finished. The framework also handles ordering out the window for you.

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify when to use `orderOut()`